# PHP - "template"

Tags: javascript, php

The title might not be clear enough, so i'll try to explain what I mean: I'm trying to create my own "template" on php, and every page contains few strings (e.g.: `{%title%}`, `{%description%}` etc.) which should be like variables and replaced by another string from the database. In order to make it even simpler & easier (& static, but for testing purposes only), I tried to do some tests with an `array` and `str_replace` function, but it didn't work.

My code (which isn't working, of course) is:

```
<?php
    str_replace(array('{%title%}', '{%description%}'), array('Example', 'Example description'), /* what the ... should I insert here? */);
?>
```

and the html (partial):

```
<title>{%title%}</title>
<meta name="description" content="{%description%}" />
```

<del>Should I use javascript (or maybe ajax) in this case? Is there any other way to do something like that?</del>

**Update:** `ob_start` was the solution. :-)

Thank you very much, and please excuse my english if I had any misspellings.

Comment: Did you read the documentation page of `str_replace`?

Comment: @Federkun yes, but I need to make my entire page as the `$subject` of this function

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
<?php
$subject = file_get_contents( "mytemplate.html" );
$keys = array(
  "{%mykey1%}",
  "{%mykey2%}"
);
$values = array(
  "myval1",
  "myval2"
);

$page = str_replace( $keys, $values, $subject );
ob_clean();
echo $page;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get what you mean, this could be a solution.

```
<?php


$string = "{%title%}, {%description%}";

$tags = array('title', 'description');
$content = array('Example title', 'Example description');

for($i = 0; $i < count($tags); $i++){
    $tag = '{%'.$tags[$i].'%}';
    $string = str_replace($tag, $content[$i], $string);
}

echo $string; // This outputs Example title, Example description

?>
```

You should of course swap the $string with the contents of the page, but I guess you can figure that out yourself.

Answer (score 0):

`ob_start()` Basic Example

```
  //starting the output cache
  ob_start();
  //register a shutdown function, 
  //so you dont have to do ob_ stuff at the end of the script
  register_shutdown_function(
    function() use(&$from,&$to){ 
      //$from,$to must be prepared 
      //(given as reference so you can fill them after register the function)
      echo str_replace($from,$to,ob_get_clean());
  });
```

But its just a point to start when you want to use ob_start(). 
Templates are normaly done in a other way. 
Read about Smarty and learn from that, if you want to do this on your own.